# iOS images cache with custom count of images in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, caching, memcached

I'm creating an app that loads a lot of different images from the web. So I have two screens. The "main" screen with UITableView with thumbnails. And the "image preview" screen with UICollectionView with full size image where user will swipe between images.

My task is to load images from network and store them to file and memory. And it's very easy to do with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). But very often I have too much images in memory and it causes memory warning. And sometimes memory cache don't have enough time to drop images and app crashes.

So the simplest solution is to set maximum image count to store in memory.

Comment: I don't thin'k issue come from cache Image or have alot of Image show in screen. because cache don't need alot of memory. You may check about reusable cell (set cell identifier or some thing like this) to save your time. If re use not good a little will crash your app. Else if reuse good cell, some time it show memory warning but app still run

Comment: App have deal with pretty big images, it's not only thumbnails. And of  course all cells are reused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any library that able to set maximum image count to store in memory. So we've made own solution and published it on [github](https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage).

Now it's easy to set

```
APSmartStorage.sharedInstance.maxObjectCount = 10;
```

'APSmartStorage' will remove random object from memory before store new one if 'maxObjectCount' were reached

Comment: I don´t think @clockwirkman need a other framework....

Answer (score 0):

The SDImageCache class has some methods:

SDImageCache::clearMemory < removes images only from array

SDImageCache::clearDisk   < deletes all

SDImageCache::cleanDisk   < better say: clean cache.

```
//Clear Image Cache
SDImageCache *imgCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] init];
[imgCache clearMemory];
[imgCache clearDisk];
imgCache = nil;
```

this is my snippet^hope it helps...

you can set a maximum cache size. via SDImageCache::maxMemoryCost, SDImageCache::maxCacheSize and SDImageCache::maxChacheAge.

Comment: when you configure the max cache size, the you must use SDImageCache::cleanDisk

Comment: I've checked that methods before create own solution. They good but anyway I should write some logic to manage images. So it's not exactly what I need